# Can the word "stale" be used on data or information?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, adjectives, formality

I know the word "stale" has one meaning as (of a check or legal claim) invalid because out of date. However, I need a word indicating that some information or data is invalid because out of data.

For example, the network latency induced will lead to stale data (that is invalid because out of date).

Can this word be still used in this scenario? Or is there another word for this purpose? Besides, a formal word is preferred.

Many thanks.

Comment: "Stale" is used in that sense all the time.

Comment: @Hotlicks So you mean stale is not only used for check or legal claim but can also be used for data?

Comment: [https://www.findwords.net/?query=data&find=a](https://www.findwords.net/?query=data&find=a)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, **stale** is the best term here and is not considered informal. A web search for *stale data* will yield many examples.